# How do I use MSBuild on a post-build event in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm using VS2010 and want to perform a post-build action to compress my JavaScript etc:

See: http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

I've never used MSBuild or Postbuild events so can anyone tell me how to add this ability to an existing web application.

Comment: Either Postbuild Event and MSBUild AfterBuild Targets allows to execute third party external command line tools, so it depends on your preferences

Answer (score 1):

Post build events are just windows batch scripts. You can use any command line tool if you want.

If you want deeper integration then you can hook in to msbuild. But if all you need is to zip up some files, just use something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and it's [command line interface.](http://www.codejacked.com/zip-up-files-from-the-command-line/)

There is a neat little example of using a the built in variables, to make it easier to write the script - http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx

Comment: Hi Preet, I think im going to use Chirpy instead to minify my files.

Comment: Does it have a command line? It looks like a VS addin. I don't know how you'd use it with post build steps then. If it's a library you could create a program that calls it with the appropriate files.